# Spring application is not loading in tomcat 7.0.47 but is loading in Tomcat 7.0.34

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I saw in spring web sockets documentation [Spring WebSockets](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) the below code under **20.4.11 Configuration and Performance**.I was surprised there is no method as well as there is no class `WebSocketTransportRegistration` present. I am using Spring web sockets 4.0.2.RELEASE.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(15 * 1000).setSendBufferSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
    }

    // ...
}
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocketTransportRegistration was only added in the 4.0.3 release so you will need to update your project to use that version (or newer) instead.

Comment: great, let me know how it goes for you.